# Submit form loaded by Ajax using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, captcha

I have a page with a list of items where I have used Ajax to load a form successfully based on a data id.

The form is itself is Ajax based which submits and validates the submission without reloading the page but instead uses Ajax itself to submit the data (tested and working on normal page setup).

I got this far with it but the Ajax on the form fails to work for me, I've tried several things including delegate etc. The form posts normally without Ajax to a new page.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction, JQuery seems to be my weakness, or maybe I'm just too far away from the solution.

## Html

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>
        <h3>test</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <a href="job-contact.php?id_job=1" class="related" data-id="1" rel="nofollow">Apply Now</a>
        <div id="jobForm1"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contactform').submit(function() {

        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('<img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');

        $("#message").slideUp(750, function() {

            $('#message').hide();

            $.post(action, values, function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if (data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            });

        });

        return false;

    });
    //end form //

    //load related content loads form on page //
    $( 'a.related' ).bind( 'click', function( e ) {  // bind the event to the element identifier // 
        var url = $( this ).attr( 'href' ); // define the anchor variable //
        var id = $( this ).attr( 'data-id' );  // define the data-id containing the record id //
        $( '#jobForm' + id ).load( url ).hide().fadeIn('slow'); // append the data id and load the content in the container div //
        e.preventDefault(); // stop browser loading new page //

        //tried everything I know here

    });//close function//

}); // close doc ready
```

Comment: How is your HTML related to your JS/jQuery code?

Comment: The javascript #jobForm' + var data-id relates to html element #jobForm1 for example where the list elements are identified by the static #jobForm and a dynamic php table row id is appended to the element to make it unique on the page. This then loads a form with dynamic fields unique to that record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're loading `#contactForm` after `a.related` is clicked, so the form doesn't exists when the document loads, hence your handler declaration does nothing.

Try adding the handler inside `$( 'a.related' ).bind`, after the form is loaded.

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) mention this exact case:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

To do it using a delegated event, you could do:

```
$( "#myList" ).on( "submit", "form", function() {
```

That way you can keep your handler where it is.

Comment: Many thanks, Jaime thanks for taking the time to solve this for me.